# How to set text formatted in Android Studio in ubuntu

Tags: android, android-studio

http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/docs/IntelliJIDEA_ReferenceCard.pdf

As Like in Eclipse if we press "ctrl+alt+f" then all text automatic formatted . how in ubuntu ?

if we use CTL + ALT + L on ubuntu then it goes logg off

How in Android Studio ubuntu ?

Comment: ohhhhh but I didn't sir :(

Comment: I think it's Ubuntu which handle the key event first. Try to change the CTRL+ALT+L action in Ubuntu just to be sure ?

Comment: No I didn't. Anyway, changing keyboard shortcut in Ubuntu is another question ^^ So I don't know, and I am using Fedora on KDE. I am sure Google will be able to help you about this one !

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Hey Now I have your answer.

You need to change Ubuntu key shortcuts for Lock Screen

For this.

Go to  `System Tools -> System Settings -> Keyboard -> Shortcuts Tab -> System -> Lock Screen`

Select the row `New Accelerator...` will be visible then press any Special key with Alpha key (like Shift + L). You changed the key shortcuts.

Now check format key in Studio.